# Hosting email and supporting client auto configuration

Tags: email-server

Is there a best way to provide email hosting such that email clients like Outlook and Mac Mail can automatically configure themselves given limited information (email + password)?

I'm guessing it might have to do with DNS entries - using [smtp|pop|imap].example.com, but I'd rather not guess if this is documented somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?  What exactly do you mean by "automatically configure themselves"?

Comment: If I go into Mac Mail and add a new account, there's an option to have the email client automatically set the account up. I only put in my name, email address and password and it tries to figure out all the other settings. I believe Outlook has the same feature.

Comment: Ah.  Interesting, never worked with Mac Mail before so didn't realize.  Outlook does not have this, unless it's part of Outlook 2007.

Comment: Looks like the auto-configure is there for Outlook 2007, but it's specifically related to Exchange 2007 (feature is called Autodiscovery and it's an Exchange feature).  http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/configuring-outlook-2007-exchange-server-2007.html

Comment: My hosted provider uses this. It has "issues"...such as ONLY outlook 2007, and IE 8 isn't supported (or wasn't 2 weeks ago)

Comment: You are trying to support email users. Find out what combination of email clients 90% of your users use, and create seperate 'configuration import' files for them.  Most mail user agents support exporting and importing configuration templates. That's what I would pursue.

Answer (score 1):

Mail clients which "discover" these things contain a list of probable values.  The list will often contain specific values for certain commonly-used domains, and otherwise guess subdomains like `mail`, `imap`, `smtp`, and `pop`, and then attempt the standard ports for each service.  It basically repeatedly tries various settings until it finds a combination which allow it to connect.  It is entirely client-side and there is no way at all to influence this from the server side (except providing sufficiently default services).

That said, thunderbird and possibly some other clients support querying a subdomain (via http) for an XML configuration file.  The subdomain is `autoconfig`.  For example, for `user@example.int`, thunderbird will query `http://autoconfig.example.int/mail/config-v1.1.xml`.  [The format of the file is described at the mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration/FileFormat/HowTo) and [a description of exactly how to set it up is available there also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration).

There was once talk of using `TXT` and `SRV` records for this, but it's unclear if this has ever been implemented.  Thunderbird in particular also has the ability to query a preinstalled XML config file and a config file at `https://live.mozillamessaging.com/autoconfig/<email-address-domain>`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Thunderbird support something like this, but it's entirely a client-side trick.  There are some semi-accepted ways to auto configure web browser proxies via DHCP, but I know of no way to do this for any common mail clients.

If you find a more satisfactory answer, it will be very email client specific.  So you might try searching (or re-asking) for the specific mail client(s) you need to support.